# When do I need to escape metacharectars? (jQuery Selectors)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, escaping

According to the jQuery docs, I need to escape metacharacters that occur in my selector strings, when they occur as a literal. However, I couldn't find very many specific examples of when and when not to escape selectors. So when and when don't I need to escape metacharacters, when they are to be interpreted as a literal, in:

Attribute selectors? ie

```
$("[attr=value]")
```

Id selectors? ie

```
$("#id")
```

Class selectors? ie

```
$(".class");
```

And, is there a way to write a function that replaces metachars in selector strings, while still preserving the beginning character? ie:

```
// replace all meta chars, preserving the id selection?
$("#id.rest$of*string")

// replace all meta chars, preserving the attribute selection?
// going back to my previous question, do I even need to escape the metachars in this situation?
$("[attr=blah.dee#foo*yay]")
```

The reason I ask this question, is because I'm working with a website that happens to have some really nasty selectors. And I don't have control over the website, so I can't go change the selectors to be nicer to work with.

THANKS!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the jQuery docs:

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters (#;&,.+*~':"!^$=>|/ ) **as a literal part of a name**, you must escape the character with two backslashes ...

All of these must be escaped:

1. id
2. class name
3. attribute name
4. attribute value
5. element name

The first four are obvious, and here's an example for the fifth. Element names in XML can contain a "." character for instance and still be [valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name).

```
<user.name>John Doe</user.name>
```

If you had to select all elements of `user.name`, then that `.` must be escaped

```
$(xml).find("user\\.name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than blatantly stealing someone else's answer, I'll point you to it: [jQuery selector value escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739695/jquery-selector-value-escaping/740168#740168), where jQuery's selector parsing method is described in detail.

The short answer: you may be in trouble since jQuery's selector parser is not 100% standards-complaint.  Per the suggestion in the linked answer, you may be able to workaround by calling the regular DOM methods (`document.getElementById()`), which will work with funny selectors, and then pass the raw DOM element to the jQuery selector.

```
$(document.getElementById("id.rest$of*string"));
```