# How to escape ":"?

Tags: jquery, jsf, escaping, seam

for example I have id like

> someform:somepanel:somebutton

When I do jQuery("#someform:somepanel:somebutton") it returns someform, how to **AUTOMATICALLY** escape that id?

**EDIT:**

I want to do something like this

```
jQuery(somefunction("#someform:somepanel:somebutton"))
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ - Third line

Comment: @jAndy its not there, can you quote the answer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If it's only this very specialized version, you can just `.replace()` the character.

```
function somefunction(selector) {
    return selector.replace(/:/, '\\\\:');
}

jQuery(somefunction("#someform:somepanel:somebutton"))
```

is then converted into

```
jQuery("#someform\\:somepanel\\:somebutton");
```

To have a more generic version, you can use a regexp:

```
function somefunction(selector) {
    return selector.replace(/(!|"|#|\$|%|\'|\(|\)|\*|\+|\,|\.|\/|\:|\;|\?|@)/g, function($1, $2) {
        return "\\\\" + $2;
    });
}
```

Comment: I found the function parameters confusing. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter gives a good explanation.

Answer (score 9):

use the double backslashes:

```
 jQuery("#someform\\:somepanel\\:somebutton")
```

Related:

- [jQuery selector value escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739695/jquery-selector-value-escaping)
- [When do I need to escape metacharectars? (jQuery Selectors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332122/when-do-i-need-to-escape-metacharectars-jquery-selectors)
- http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

  - If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;?@[\]^{|}~` ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with **two** backslashes: `\\.` For example, if you have an an element with `id="foo.bar"`, you can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`. The W3C CSS specification contains the [complete set of rules regarding valid CSS selectors.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier)

---

Update #1

After your comment in regards to *auto* escaping the best method I see is to create a function within the string object like so

```
String.prototype.escape = function()
{
    return this.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/])/g,'\\$1')
}
```

you can also specifically define a function for the colons like so:

```
String.prototype.escape_colon = function()
{
     return this.replace(/:/,'\\$1')
}
```

and use like so:

```
jQuery("someform:somepanel:somebutton".escape())
```

but this will cause issues on pseudo selectors such as:

```
jQuery("someform:somepanel:somebutton:first".escape())
```

the `:first` selector will be escaped and therefore you will not find your element.

but y our best bet will be to build a string parser within the prototype to replace where it finds a specific set of chars such as:

```
jQuery("someform(_e(:))somepanel(_e(:))somebutton:first".escape())
```

this way you can define what you want to escape, but if that was the case you may as well escape them yourself.

Comment: I know I can do that, but I want to do jQuery(somefunction("#someform:somepanel:somebutton"))

Comment: Updated my answer, you need to be more clearer with your questions in future.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
jQuery("#someform\\:somepanel\\:somebutton")
```

Comment: I know I can do that, but I want to do jQuery(somefunction("#someform:somepanel:somebutton"))

Comment: @01: I am not sure I follow. Isn't escaping the `:` from your above comment what you are looking for?

Comment: is there "somefunction" that can AUTOMATICALLY add \\ to the string before the : ?

Comment: @01: Yes, there is as @jAndy has it in his answer already. Recap: just call `somefunction` and return `yourID.replace(/:/, '\\:');` from it.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/), they have a handy helper function to do just that:

> escapeClientId(id) - Escaped JSF ids with semi colon to work with
>   jQuery.

To call it:

```
PrimeFaces.escapeClientId("someform:somepanel:somebutton")
```

which returns:

```
#someform\\:somepanel\\:somebutton
```

Internally, it just calls `replace(/:/g,"\\:")` and adds the `#`, so you could use that, too.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a function to escape colons for JSF in jQuery:

```
//USAGE: $(espaceIdForJSF('#someId:anotherId'));
function escapeIdForJSF(id) {
   return id.replace(/:/g,"\\:").replace(/\./g,"\\.");
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use this trick: `jQuery($('myid'))`

Reason: I'm using "prototype" to look up element by id, then I pass result to jQuery.

Pros: easier to read.
Cons: need Prototype and jQuery, but RichFaces uses Prototype anyway.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery `3.0` provides an escape function:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/

```
$( "#" + $.escapeSelector( evilId ) );
```