# jQuery selectors in Composite components, why it doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, jsf, composite-component

I try to select JSF component by using jQuery selector. Composite component ***.xhtml*** and **.js** relative code are separated, so I pass `cc.cliendId` in variables as following:

```
var variables = {};
variables.formid = "#{cc.clientId}";
```

And in ***.js** file I try to use it as following: `$('[id="'+variables.formid+'"]')` it works and returns me a whole div, but the following code doesn't work, it returns an empty object `[]`:

```
function escapeColons(selector) {
    return selector.replace(/(!|"|#|\$|%|\'|\(|\)|\*|\+|\,|\.|\/|\:|\;|\?|@)/g, function($1, $2) {
        return "\\\\" + $2;
    });
}

 $("#" + escapeColons(variables.formid))
```

The function which escapes colons is taken from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4792023/947111

If I write `$("#" + "form\\:range_chooser")`, **range_chooser** is a **id** of my **composite component**, it works.

Comment: so what returns: `escapeColons(variables.formid)`?

Comment: `form\\:range_chooser` as a string

Comment: Try to declare the `variables` without `var`. I can't see the full picture of your JS scopes....

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't solve your concrete problem, but I've always found it easier to change the separator char to something non-conflicting than to constantly escape ids. You can do this by adding a context parameter to your Web.xml. ie:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.SEPARATOR_CHAR</param-name>
    <param-value>-</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I should probably add that if you have colons hardcoded everywhere, you'd have to go back and change all of those. So depending on your setup, it may be more trouble than it's worth.

**Edit**

If you need to leave the separator char the way it is, you should be able to simplify that javascript a bit:

```
function escapeColons(selector) {
    return selector.replace(/(!|"|#|\$|%|\'|\(|\)|\*|\+|\,|\.|\/|\:|\;|\?|@)/g,"\\$1");
}

$("#" + escapeColons(variables.formid))
```

Works for me anyway.