# jQuery: escaping plus sign in selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a dom element:

```
<li id="foo+bar"></li>
```

I want to address that element (using jQuery if possible) and I try:

```
$("#foo+bar")
```

and I've also tried also escaping it:

```
$("#foo\+bar")
```

..but neither seems to work, because (I'm guessing) jQuery can't handle the plus sign it seems. Unfortunately I don't really have the option of changing the id value, so:

Is there a way to make jQuery get the correct dom, or how could I approach this problem?

Comment: Did you forget to put the `#` before the id name?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739695/jquery-selector-value-escaping

Comment: C'mon, folks, it's **[in the jQuery FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F).**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try escaping it with two backslashes.

```
$("#foo\\+bar")
```

Comment: works fine, thank you.. and yes Matt Ball, it's in the jQuery FAQ I see it, sorry I didn't find it there first.

Comment: Keep in mind although that the **escape** code is in the FAQ, it isn't specifically pointing to your `+`, but it is (kinda explicitly too!) reffering to actual valid ID-problems like the `:` and the `.`.

Answer (score 6):

Well, the problem is probably that a `+` shouldn't be there.

[HTML 4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) says:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

So any workaround is still based on a faulty start, so might stop working anytime. You really should change that id.

Comment: It's fine in HTML5. For a jQuery selector, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115636/jquery-escaping-plus-sign-in-selector/6115667#6115667

Comment: It might be, so in an HTML5 only situation that would be cool. As HTML5, though wildly used for fun, is not yet a finished spec as far as I know, I would advice against coding for that.

Comment: But my point is that any solution is fighting against something that shouldn't be there: experience tells me that that will mean that somewhere in the future your code will randomly break because something (jquery, browser, whatever) has stopped supporting your workaround. Anything you do (have not tried it, the double escape by @ole_melhus probably works) is dangerous ground as far as i'm concerned.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe + is a valid character in an id.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a
>   letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods
>   (".").

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name