# JQuery selector form element php array

Tags: jquery, escaping, selector, character

im trying to use the code below to select a form element (i retrieve the values to validate the text)

```
$('#box1 [name=item[]]').val();
$('#box2 [name=item[]]').val();
```

i'm trying to get the value of the following

```
<form..>
   <div id='box1'> <input type='text' name='item[]'/> </div>
   <div id='box1'> <input type='text' name='item[]'/> </div>
</form>
```

I need to use 'item[]' with the square brackets [ ] because php can retrieve this data as an array

```
$data = $_REQUEST['item'];
```

Would return an array containing all the data in 'item'

The problem is the $('#box [name=item[]]').val() doesn't work, how would I get it to work or would there be another way to do this?

Comment: you can try to escape your selector with `\` - see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739695/jquery-selector-value-escaping for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `[` and `]` in the jQuery selector, as they have a special meaning (attribute selectors):

```
$('#box1 [name="item\\[\\]"]').val();
$('#box2 [name="item\\[\\]"]').val();
```

[jQuery documentation states:](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: \.

Answer (score 1):

if you could give the inputs a classname like "input_item" and than

```
$("input.input_item").each(function() {

    // do something with $(this).val()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
$('#box1 input[name="item[]"]').val()
```

I've just added double quotes around the 'name' value and added the 'input' selector to the selector value.

Demo  - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/JbW5m/