# jQuery - Query for textbox by value? (value contains quotation marks)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string in JavaScript that contains a quote mark - for example, `Don't click this checkbox` or `He said "hi"`. I am trying to find a checkbox that has the exact same value.

For my first example, I have the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Don\'t click this checkbox">
```

And my variable q has the string `Don't click this checkbox` in it. To try and query for this checkbox, I have the following code. Where am I going wrong?

```
q = q.replace("'", "\'").replace("\"", "\\"");
var $checkbox = $("input:checkbox[value='" + q + "']");
```

Comment: What do you get when you add the line `console.log($checkbox)` at the end?

Comment: Why does the value need the \?  Can't you just set the value to `Don't click this checkbox`?

Comment: [This related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739695/jquery-selector-value-escaping) might be helpful. I got it working using `var q = "Don\\\\'t click this checkbox";` if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the second replace function:  `.replace("\"", "\\"");`

Since you have a double quote in a string delimted by double quotes, you have to escape the inside double quote.  Or, make it easy on yourself and use single quotes:

```
q = q.replace("'", "\'").replace('"', '\"');
```

Comment: I was thinking about this. My main problem is that I tested this code with just the first replacement of single quotes, and it still didn't work, so something was already going wrong with just that. Do I need more backslashes like Andrew suggested?