# Check box dynamically added to jQuery data table not showing up

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a check box to a single column jQuery data table using

```
dataTable.fnAddData( ["<input type=\"checkbox\">"]);
```

I don't get any error messages but nothing shows up.

Comment: are you supposed to be escaping the `"` in `\"checkbox\">`?

Comment: I tried <input type='checkbox'> with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to do

```
dataTable.fnAddData( ["<input type='checkbox' id='checkboxID'/>"]);
jQuery('#checkBoxID').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `\` before escape character.

```
dataTable.fnAddData( ["<input type=\\"checkbox\\">"]);
```

Check this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739695/jquery-selector-value-escaping).

Comment: \\"  caused "SyntaxError: missing ] after element list" with Firebug.

Comment: `['<input type="checkbox" />']` try this one.

Comment: I tried ['<input type="checkbox" />'].  No errors but nothing showed up.

Comment: I saw that.  It was one of the first things I tried.  I removed the name and ID to make it as simple as possible and also the someOtherDataFromAnOtherColumn since that that would be put in another column would it not?  Thanks.