# match invalid html tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I select non valid html element using jquery, I have image with invalid tag `left;` like

```
<img left; src="..." />
```

This semicolon is problematic part, I tried with `$('img[left]').removeAttr('left').attr("align","left");` but that not match my semicolon;

How to do this?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/740168/66580

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$('img[left\\;]').removeAttr('left;').attr("align","left");`

Comment: tried with $('img[left\\;]'); but it fetch nothing, thanks though.

Comment: What browser are you using. I tried this in firefox and it fetched the element.