# Press a unique button do the actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So as I started using JavaScript and jQuery, I have a question with unique div.

Is is possible in the JavaScript to make a unique div name then do the action `onclick`?

http://jsfiddle.net/agmr2ytd/4/

Example HTML:

```
<div id="favoriteXBSbQG6fNlObroDG4ML2l9VRO/yNpvIFxL0Qjr6bP2A=">
    <a href="#" id="XBSbQG6fNlObroDG4ML2l9VRO/yNpvIFxL0Qjr6bP2A=" class="btn btn-danger">Me</a>
</div>
<div id="favoriteakkbN3eo8h0Q7S4ouHqMX7cU9vNLNKw3llO/PK0e9qI=">
    <a href="#" id="akkbN3eo8h0Q7S4ouHqMX7cU9vNLNKw3llO/PK0e9qI=" class="btn btn-danger">Me 2</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('.favorite').click(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var verify = element.attr("id");
        alert(verify);
        $('#favorite'+verify).hide();
    });

});
```

When I press a first `a` from div I wanna get the id value as a `alert` and hide it.

Comment: You have element with the class of `"favorite"`.

Comment: will also have problems having special characters in `id` which will have to be escaped ... see selectors section of jQuery API

Comment: @DavidThomas Sorry, I don't get it. What you mean?

Comment: @charlietfl I cannot view the jQuery API site normaly, there are no letters in the site dunno why :D, so basicly removing special characters will fix the problem?

Comment: special characters is only part of your problem, what @DavidThomas meant was you don't have a `class=favorite` which is what your selector is looking for

Comment: same code, just adding class to tags  http://jsfiddle.net/agmr2ytd/6/

Comment: No, it wouldn't. It appears that you don't know what you're doing, which is fine, but the onus is on you to learn. Start with css selectors: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Comment: Think he wanted to select anchor using its parent which has an ID that starts with `favorite...` - look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, for attributes `^=` means "attribute value starts with":

```
$(function() {
    $('[id^=favorite] a').click(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var verify = element.attr("id");
        alert(verify);
        $('#favorite'+verify.replace(/([ #;?%&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g,'\\$1')).hide();
    });
});
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agmr2ytd/10/) <-

Your ID has to be escaped, [used this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739695/jquery-selector-value-escaping#answer-3113742) for solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set class = favorite to your divs, then this is working:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/agmr2ytd/8/)

jQuery / javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('.favorite').click(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var verify = element.attr("id");
        alert(verify);
        var tohide = document.getElementById(verify);
        tohide.style.display = 'none';
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="favoriteXBSbQG6fNlObroDG4ML2l9VRO/yNpvIFxL0Qjr6bP2A=" class="favorite">
    <a href="#" id="XBSbQG6fNlObroDG4ML2l9VRO/yNpvIFxL0Qjr6bP2A=" class="btn btn-danger">Me</a>
</div>
<div id="favoriteakkbN3eo8h0Q7S4ouHqMX7cU9vNLNKw3llO/PK0e9qI="  class="favorite">
    <a href="#" id="akkbN3eo8h0Q7S4ouHqMX7cU9vNLNKw3llO/PK0e9qI=" class="btn btn-danger">Me 2</a>
</div>
```