# JQuery selector: how to escape special characters in a variable inserted into the selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, special-characters, html-escape-characters

I have a variable that I want to use in a selector but the variable contains special characters. Is there a way to do this?

```
hasSpecialChr='dynamicVar[1][3]';

element = $('li.parent#'+hasSpecialChr);
```

Edit: Answered in first comment below.

Comment: Quick google search of your question : https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

Comment: embarrassment ensues...

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739695/jquery-selector-value-escaping

Comment: @Phil It happens to everyone :P Just has to be careful!

Comment: As stated by @Karl-André Gagnon The answer is to use a function to strip out the characters as described by JQuery docs https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
hasSpecialChr='dynamicVar\\[1\\]\\[3\\]';
element = $('li.parent#'+hasSpecialChr);
```

Comment: I don't think this works.  I think they need $("#dynamicVar\\\[1\\\]\\\[3\\\]");

Comment: yeah i tried it, it doesn't work. the \\ just escapes the first character after it.

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem:

```
s.replace(/[^a-z\d\s]+/gi, "");
```

removes all except letters, numbers and white space.

```
hasSpecialChr='dynamicVar[1][3]';
hasSpecialChr.replace(/[^a-z\d\s]+/gi, "");
element = $('li.parent#'+hasSpecialChr);
```