# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #F-R33^:^F-BC12^:^F-N10

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a cancel button and upon clicking it needs to remove the said div. My code reads like that

```
var search_id       = $(this).parent().attr('data-id'); 

// search id is F-R33^:^F-BC12^:^F-N10

$("div[data-id="+search_id+"]").remove();
```

This line is giving me syntax error, what i think is for ^:^ this expression. 
how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle demonstrating this? I can probably help you better when I see what else you are doing as well.

Comment: Okay you can do CSS3 Selectors but you need to use single quotes, https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ In my comment below notice I added single quotes before and after the double quotes

Comment: $("div[data-id='"+search_id+"']").remove();

Comment: I created JSFiddle here showing it working, https://jsfiddle.net/ruqjhLuj/

Comment: $("div[data-id='"+search_id+"']").remove();
This is working here in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hvut98s4/9/
But is not working in my code. need to do something else. Thanks by the way.

Comment: Some ideas: [jQuery selector value escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739695/jquery-selector-value-escaping)

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way - give that div a class e.g. divClass

$(".divClass"+search_id).remove();
Or
$(".div"+search_id).remove();